# Golang convert string in to an array

Tags: arrays, string, go

I have a string that I want to convert into an array.

```golang
str := "[\"firsName\",\"lastName\", \"email\"]"
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(str))
fmt.Println(strings.Split(str, ","))
```

This results:

```
[["firsName" "lastName"  "email"]]
```

I want the output like this:

```
["firsName" "lastName"  "email"]
```

I can get this by using strings.Replace function. But is there any better way to do this?

Go Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/HYr7ILt74OW

Comment: The example string is valid json, so you could just use `json.Unmarshal` with `[]string` as the target argument. https://go.dev/play/p/sxFpIHiFbaW

Comment: instead of split use trim ```fmt.Println(strings.Trim(str, ","))```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strings.Trim` to remove the trailing and leading unwanted character.

```golang
trimmedStr := strings.Trim("[\"firsName\",\"lastName\", \"email\"]", "[]")
fmt.Println(strings.Split(trimmedStr, ","))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str := "[\"firsName\",\"lastName\", \"email\"]"
var strArr []string
_ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &strArr)
fmt.Println(strArr)
```